# vue3 script setup not working with revogrid

Tags: vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I have a vue3 app, in which I'd like to keep using the standard composition api style. Unfortunately, RevoGrid doesn't seem to like it. RevoGrid works with an options api style , but the equivalent  doesn't render any content. The wrappers are there, but that's it. I thought the 2 script snippets below were functionally identical, but that does not seem to be the case. The only real difference I can see is that the options api version registers the VGrid component locally. I was under the impression that when using  one didn't need to register a component, you just import it and then use it in the template. What is different about RevoGrid, and how can avoid having to code these couple of views that use it with an old style ?

```
<script>
  import VGrid from "@revolist/vue3-datagrid";

  export default {
    components: {
      VGrid,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        columns: [{ prop: "name" }, { prop: "details" }],
        rows: [
          { name: "Joe", details: "Stuff 1", },
          { name: "Jane", details: "Stuff 2", },
          { name: "John", details: "Stuff 3", }
        ]
      };
    },
  };
</script>

<script setup>
    import VGrid from "@revolist/vue3-datagrid";
    
    const props = defineProps({
      columns: [{ prop: "name" }, { prop: "details" }],
      rows: [
        { name: "Joe", details: "Stuff 1", },
        { name: "Jane", details: "Stuff 2", },
        { name: "John", details: "Stuff 3", }
      ]
    });
</script>

<template>
  <div id="revoEx">
    <VGrid
      theme="compact"
      :source="rows"
      :columns="columns"
    ></VGrid>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your data as actual data in Options API but for some reason you moved it as props in Composition API. The props should be provided by the parent component.

`defineProps` expect an object for each prop, you provided arrays, which have no meaningful properties for `defineProps` so basically your data arrays are ignored and the columns and rows are `undefined`. That's why nothing is rendered.

You need to convert it back to data:

```
<script setup>
    import VGrid from "@revolist/vue3-datagrid";
    
    const columns = [{ prop: "name" }, { prop: "details" }];
    const rows = [
        { name: "Joe", details: "Stuff 1", },
        { name: "Jane", details: "Stuff 2", },
        { name: "John", details: "Stuff 3", }
      ];

</script>

<template>
  <div id="revoEx">
    <VGrid
      theme="compact"
      :source="rows"
      :columns="columns"
    ></VGrid>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Sorry, defineProps was grasping at straws. My first version was just like yours, only wrapped in ref() eg:     const columns = ref([{ prop: "name" }, { prop: "details" }]); Any idea why ref() wrapers don't work?

Comment: @ShanePetroff you don't need refs here since the data is static

Comment: Yes, the data here are static, but this is just a minimal version. A realistic version would have the data loaded from a REST api. I assumed that I'd declare them as ref([]), then load them onMounted(). Oddly using refs renders less than using props.